# Jquery datepicker beforeShowDay still clickable even all days should already be not selectable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

[image]

I am using jquery ui for datepicker and I am trying to disable some dates. I have searched that we can achieve this via beforeShowDay on datepicker initialisation. However I cant seem to make it work with the following code:

```js
$(function(){
  $('.my-datepicker').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(d){                                                               
              return [ false, "test-class", "Not available" ];
          }
      });
}());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="form-control my-datepicker" name="StartDate" id="StartDate">
```

I am able to make it work in the snippet above but I really cannot understand why in my actual app the datepicker shows but all dates are still selectable.

When I add a breakpoint on the beforeShowDay return the code does enter that function but still all days are selectable.

I am running out of ideas so perhaps somebody have encountered a similar problem and can give some ideas where to look.

```
$(document).on('click', '.addEvent', function(){

                var params = {
                    'SWFCustomerLocationID': $(this).data('swfcustlocid')
                }

                // Load the SWFCustomerDetails Modal
                $.get(base_url + '/settings/components/createPickupOrDeliverySchedule.php', params, function(response){
                    $(document).find("#createPickupOrDeliveryScheduleForm").remove();
                    $(document).find('body').append(response.html);
                    $("#createPickupOrDeliveryScheduleForm").modal('show');

                    initializeInstrumentAccordion();

                    $('.chosen-select').chosen({width: '100%'});

                    var startDate = Date.parse(response.StartDate);
                    var endDate = Date.parse(response.EndDate);

                    $('#StartDate').datepicker({
                        startDate: new Date(startDate),
                        endDate: new Date(endDate),
                        dateFormat: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
                        // beforeShowDay: function(d){                                
                        //     var day = d.getDate();

                        //     if (day < 10) {
                        //         day = "0" + day;
                        //     }

                        //     var month = d.getMonth() + 1;
                        //     if (month < 10) {
                        //         month = "0" + month;
                        //     }
                        //     var year = d.getFullYear();

                        //     var dString = `${year}-${month}-${day}`;
                        //     var result = [ false, "", "Not available" ];

                        //     return result;
                        // }
                        beforeShowDay: function(d){                                

                            return [false, "", "Not available"];
                        }
                    });
                });
            })
```

Comment: The reason could be css overwitten . Can u share your all html here? We can't understand from code u entered.

Comment: Hi @Çağrı The input element for the date picker is exactly like the one above. I load the element via ajax and then when I append it to the body, I open the content inside a modal and I run the initialization of the datepicker exactly like the one above.

Comment: Can u share your ajax code here also. problem should be about reinitialize.

Comment: @Çağrı I updated the post and added the code

Comment: I updated code . Check the answer again please .

Answer (score 1):

You should firstly destroy then reinitialize datepicker.
Can u  put

`$('#StartDate').datepicker("destroy");`

before

```
  $('#StartDate').datepicker({
                        startDate: new Date(startDate),
                        endDate: new Date(endDate),
                        dateFormat: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
                        // beforeShowDay: function(d){                                
                        //     var day = d.getDate();

                        //     if (day < 10) {
                        //         day = "0" + day;
                        //     }

                        //     var month = d.getMonth() + 1;
                        //     if (month < 10) {
                        //         month = "0" + month;
                        //     }
                        //     var year = d.getFullYear();

                        //     var dString = `${year}-${month}-${day}`;
                        //     var result = [ false, "", "Not available" ];

                        //     return result;
                        // }
                        beforeShowDay: function(d){                                

                            return [false, "", "Not available"];
                        }
                    });
```

and for first initialize use it document ready

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('.my-datepicker').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(d){              
    console.log("dsad")
              return [ true, "test-class", "Not available" ];
          }
      });
});
```

don't use with code below because it always calls for every open .

```
$(function(){
  $('.my-datepicker').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(d){                                                               
              return [ true, "test-class", "Not available" ];
          }
      });
}());
```

Comment: Thanks for helping. I tried it but still the same result, the days are still clickable.

Comment: I edited one thing more u should change your first method u should call first in document ready not function . Because that function alwaws call befor open . so it doesn't important what u change later

Answer (score 1):

You need some sort of condition to ensure that you have either a `true` or `false` result in your Array.

For example, if you want to make Saturday or Sunday unselectable, you can use `.getDay()` to find the day of the Week. Consider the following code:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.my-datepicker').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(d) {
      var result = [true, "good day", "Available"];
      if (d.getDay() == 0 || d.getDay() == 6) {
        result = [false, "bad day", "Not available"];
      }
      return result;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="form-control my-datepicker" name="StartDate" id="StartDate">
```

As you can see, only Days of the Week can be selected. Your code has no condition, so all days result in False. You need to determine which days should be True or False.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Twisty. I disabled all days to be unselectable just to test the disabling of days does reflect in the calendar. I tried adding your script but all days were still selectable. There could be something that overrides the result of beforeShowDay function but I am not sure where it is.

Comment: @bananaCute would check Console for any errors. Also review to ensure all your Libraries are loading properly. Do you have any conflicts?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for trying to help.

Turns out that the datepicker that is used is bootstrap-datepicker. I got confused as both jquery-ui and bootstrap-datepicker were added as dependency and thought the datepicker I am using is from the jquery-ui.

Here's the correct reference that I should have used:
https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/options.html#beforeshowday

Hopefully this will also help somebody who might encounter the same problem.